# Navigate URL in iframe with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have this code, to navigate a URL with javascript in an iframe, but it does not work. Why?

For example, I want navigate to `site.com` when I click link1.

```
<script language="javascript">
function nav()
{
window.navigate('http://site.com',target="DBox");
}   
</script>   


<a href="javascript:nav();">link1</a>

<iframe name="DBox" src="http://example" frameborder="0" style="width:100%;height:100%"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Simple HTML:

```
<a target="DBox" href="http://site.com">link1</a>
```

Or with just call this with JavaScript:

```
window.open("http://site.com", "DBox");
```

Comment: i want navigate URL with `javascript`. this code is not good for my question! :)

Comment: Sorry, I have added a solution with JavaScript now too.

Answer (score 1):

This will be navigate to url in the same window.

```
window.top.location.href = "http://example.com";
```